# A bill or the bill

Tags: word-choice

Should it be "pay a bill" or "the bill"?

"My friend left. So I had to pay the bill." I am talking about being in a restaurant.

Answer (score 2):

"My friend left. So I had to pay the bill." - This is the correct version under normal conditions.

In a restaurant we expect to receive a bill. We usually receive only one bill and this is therefore referred to as "the" bill.

---

If you say, "My friend left. So I had to pay a bill", there is an implication that you don't usually pay bills and that you may be indignant that you had to in this case. For example:

A: You look annoyed

B: Yes, I am annoyed, I had to pay **a** bill today!

A: But we all have to pay bills.

B: Well I don't, I expect my friends to pay - especially when they have invited me!

A: What bill did you have to pay?

B: I had to pay **a** restaurant bill. I went with a friend. My friend left. So I had to pay **the** bill.